# Calculate unique time from time intervals in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, logic

I have a situation where I need to calculate the unique number of seconds where a user plays a video. I get an array *playbackArray* in which I get the position where the user started playing the video(*beginPosition*) and the position where user stopped playing the video(*endPosition*).

I have an array like this:

```
    let playbackArray = [
        {
            beginPosition: 0,
            endPosition: 30, // endPosition - beginPosition = 30
            blockNum: 0
        },
        {
            beginPosition: 45,
            endPosition: 65, // endPosition - beginPosition = 20
            blockNum: 1
        },
        {
            beginPosition: 55,
            endPosition: 85, // endPosition - beginPosition = 30
// but only 20 new seconds (65s - 85s) so total video playback is 30 + 20 + 20 = 70s.
            blockNum: 2
        }
    ]
```

> Basically, if there are overlapping time in the blocks in array, I
>   have to remove those overlapping time interval and calculate only
>   unique time from this array.

1 way I see is to somehow run a loop on this array and iterate through each block and compare beginPosition of current block with endPosition of previous block and

1. If there is no overlap, add this difference in another array.
2. If there is an overlap, then compare beginPosition of current block with beginPosition of all the previous blocks and try to deduct the difference into this array.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: And how should the resulting `blockNum`s be chosen?

Comment: @ScottSauyet, the blockNums can be chosen in any way.

Comment: The brute force way would be to use a Set of all the seconds watched. No logic and guaranteed unique. :)

Comment: @HollyLeaves: I think you misunderstand the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the intervals are first sorted by their beginning period, then we can add to a growing list of intervals (`-[--]-`) our test interval (`-<-->-`) based on three cases:

```
// 1: Ignore current interval
      ----[--<--->--]----
      ----[---------]---- 

// 2: Merge top and current
      ----[--<---]-->----
      ----[---------]---- 

// 3: Add current to stack
      ----[---]---<-->---
      ----[---]---[--]---
```

Here is an implementation which does that.  The sample data covers all these cases, and doesn't start sorted.  You can remove the `sort` line (and the `slice` call above it) if your data will always start sorted by interval beginning:

```js
// Example: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] //=> 'd'
const last = stack => stack[stack.length - 1] 
// Example: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] //=> ['a', 'b', 'c']
const init = stack => stack.slice(0, stack.length - 1) 
const start = interval => interval.beginPosition
const end = interval => interval.endPosition

const consolidateOverlaps = (intervals) => 
    intervals.slice(0) // don't mutate original array
    .sort((a, b) => start(a) < start(b) ? -1 : start(a) > start(b) ? 1 : 0)
    .reduce((stack, curr) => start(curr) < end(last(stack))
      ? end(curr) < end(last(stack)) 
        ? stack // Case 1
        : init(stack).concat(Object.assign(last(stack), {endPosition: end(curr)})) // Case 2
      : stack.concat(curr) // Case 3
    , [{endPosition: -Infinity}]) // base case to start reduction
    .slice(1) // remove that (now unnecessary) base case

const playbackArray = [
  {beginPosition: 0, endPosition: 30, blockNum: 0},
  {beginPosition: 45, endPosition: 65, blockNum: 1},
  {beginPosition: 55, endPosition: 85, blockNum: 2},
  {beginPosition: 90, endPosition: 110, blockNum: 3},
  {beginPosition: 95, endPosition: 100, blockNum: 4},
  {beginPosition: 20, endPosition: 40, blockNum: 5},
  {beginPosition: 130, endPosition: 200, blockNum: 6},
  {beginPosition: 140, endPosition: 250, blockNum: 7},
  {beginPosition: 150, endPosition: 225, blockNum: 8},
]

console.log(consolidateOverlaps(playbackArray))
```

Note that the resulting `blockNums` are fairly arbitrary now.  Turning this result into total seconds should be easy:

```
consolidateOverlaps(playbackArray)
  .map(interval => interval.endPosition - interval.beginPosition)
  .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
```

(and these two lines could fold into the original function if you have no need for the list of intervals.)

Answer (score 0):

Awesome challenge.

I will iterate between the time spans and determine how much time it is considere as repeat. For this i thought on the next possible cases.

1. timeA starts inside timeB AND timeA ends after timeB ends
2. timeA starts inside timeB AND timeA ends before timeB ends
3. timeA ends insides timeB AND timeA starts before timeB starts
4. timeA ends after timeB ends

I hope this is what you were looking for :)

```js
let playbackArray = [{
    beginPosition: 0,
    endPosition: 30, // endPosition - beginPosition = 30
    blockNum: 0
  },
  {
    beginPosition: 45,
    endPosition: 65, // endPosition - beginPosition = 20
    blockNum: 1
  },
  {
    beginPosition: 55,
    endPosition: 85, // endPosition - beginPosition = 30
    // but only 20 new seconds (65s - 85s) so total video playback is 30 + 20 + 20 = 70s.
    blockNum: 2
  }
]

let repeat=0;
let time = 0;


for(var i =0; i<playbackArray.length; i++){
  time += playbackArray[i].endPosition - playbackArray[i].beginPosition;

  for(var j=i+1; j<playbackArray.length; j++){
    if(playbackArray[i].beginPosition > playbackArray[i+1].beginPosition ) {
    //play i starts inside play  j
      if(playbackArray[i].endPosition < playbackArray[i+1].endPosition ) {
        //All play i is inside play j
        repeat += playbackArray[i].endPosition - playbackArray[i].beginPosition;
      } else {
        //Play i ends after play j
        repeat += playbackArray[j].endPosition - playbackArray[i].beginPosition;
      }
    } 
    if(playbackArray[i].endPosition > playbackArray[j].beginPosition ) {
      //play i ends after play j started
       if(playbackArray[i].endPosition > playbackArray[j].endPosition ) {
       //play i ends after play j ended
       repeat += playbackArray[j].endPosition - playbackArray[i].beginPosition; 
      } else {
        //play i ends inside play j
        repeat += playbackArray[i].endPosition - playbackArray[j].beginPosition; 
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log("Total time:"+time,"Repeated time:"+repeat);
var res = time-repeat;
console.log("Real time:"+res);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is a simpler and great answer but the only problem with this answer is that it fails in the case the beginPosition and endPosition are not sorted(in an order).